# Seeking help for vimscript about markdown

Tags: vim, neovim

Currently, I'm using a convenient mapping in my vimrc for creating markdown links:

```
autocmd Filetype markdown inoremap <buffer> <silent> ,a [](<++>) <++><Esc>F[a
```

But I want to improve it. Here's my needs:

"In markdown filetype, hit `,a` , if under the cursor is a word or in visual mode, use the url in yank `*` to make current word or selection area a markdown link **automatically**,

```
etc:
word  ==>  [word](url in the yank *)
```

, else just gave me a empty link area like above.

And also, I wounder how it could be implement with snippet rather than vimscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hand cranked way, not very compact but hopefully legible:

```
function! CloseBracket(type)
    let l:wrap = "[\<C-r>\"](\<C-r>+)"
    if a:type ==? 'v'
        execute "normal! gvs" . l:wrap
    else
        let l:char = matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.')
        if l:char =~ '^\s*$'
            execute "normal! i[]()\<esc>hh"
            call feedkeys('i')
        else
            let l:reg = @"
            let @" = expand("<cword>")
            echom 'mode: ' . a:type
            if mode() ==? 'n'
                execute "normal! ciw" . l:wrap
            endif
            let @" = l:reg
        endif
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>a :<C-u>call CloseBracket('n')<CR>
xnoremap <leader>a :<C-u>call CloseBracket('v')<CR>
```

Explanation:

- Two mappings to call a single function with an argument that states of its been called from normal or visual mode
- If normal mode then check if cursor is on whitespace, if so then insert empty anchor syntax leaving cursor in square brackets
- If normal mode and cursor over word then word is wrapped in square brackets and + register is inserted in parentheses
- If visual selection then visual selection is wrapped in square brackets and + register is inserted in parentheses
- Doesn't override registers
- Single undo action

Limitation:

- Doesn't work on visual line, assume you would select the desired text first
- Not tested against the + register as that register doesn't work on my phone's terminal emulator, see first line of the function which is set as the + register if needs tweaking

Comment: Really decent job, but I got some questions. Is `\<C-r>` equals to `\<C-r\>` ? Why in `execute "normal! i[]()\<esc>F[i"` the last `i` won't take effact, and have to use `call feedkeys('i')` instead?

Comment: Is \<C-r> equals to \<C-r\> ? TBH I'm not sure, I don't think so. The initial back slash is to escapee the sequence so a left chevron isn't entered. The feedkeys is a bit of a hack to leave us in insert mode, otherwise the *normal!* Command would drop us out back into normal mode once it ends.

Comment: @BigFish See `:help :normal`: *"If {commands} does not finish a command, the last one will be aborted as if <Esc> or <C-C> was typed."* As for `\<C-r>`, see `:help expr-"` which describes the rules for double quoted strings: *"\<xxx> Special key named "xxx". E.g. "\<C-W>" for CTRL-W. This is for use in mappings."*

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to snippets with this kind of placeholders (`<++>`), [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template) provides a [`link` snippet](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/after/template/markdown/link.template) that expands almost exactly as your mapping.

There is a also a [surrounding mode](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/doc/workflows.md#surrounding-with-a-snippet).

By default, the current selection will be used in the *text* field. If you type '2' before triggering the visual surrounding, it'll go in the *url* field.

EDIT: If you wanted to do it by hand, the easiest way would be to use `s` to substitute the selection with what you wish to insert, and remember that the cut characters are in the default register (which is messed by this simple solution)

```
" CTRL-G_U permits to enable redo
xnoremap <buffer> ,a s[<c-r>"]()<c-g>U<left>
" default selection with: current-inner-word, fallback to the other definition
nmap     <buffer> viw,a

" For some reason, I cannot make the following work without using a variable
" xnoremap <buffer> ,else s[](<c-r>")<c-r>=repeat("\<C-G>u\<left>", strwidth(@")+3)<cr>
" Any way, as redo is quite funny here, let's use directly
xnoremap <buffer> ,else s[](<c-r>")<esc>F]i
nmap viw,else
```

Other approaches consist in first append after backquote+> mark, then inserting before backquote+< mark. They leave the default register unmodified. But they definitively don't support redo. They are not adapted to insert the old selection in multiple places either.

Comment: Thank for the recommendation. What's the difference between mu-template and ultisnips? Also, I still want to know how to make it work with vimscript, cause I want learn from it.

Comment: I took over the maintenance of mu-template long before other _snippet_ plugins came into existence. As it uses the old placeholder system, it's less sexy than utilsnip & co. The user base is much, much, smaller. But it does what I need, it permits to write really complex snippets, have snippet including other snippets... You'll find on [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7466/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-snippets-plugins/7467#7467) other information regarding its specificities.

Comment: I've expanded my answer on the topic of doing it by hand. Which, I don't recommand -- I did it in lh-brackets and lh-cpp. The result can be seen in the `lh#map#surround()` function.